# Spring WebApp running on Tomcat throws error

Tags: spring, tomcat, configuration, web.xml

I was trying to run my webapp.war in Tomcat. It throws an Error. I was trying to solve this problem, but didn't find the right solution.
Start running the spring application in Tomcat throws following errors:

```
019-09-10 22:52:29.910  INFO 19788 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] com.de.webshop.Application        : Starting Application v1.0-SNAPSHOT on LAPTOP-VG5UK9MV with PID 19788 (C:\de\Webshop\target\Webshop\WEB-INF\classes started by JS in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin)
2019-09-10 22:52:29.921  INFO 19788 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] com.de.webshop.Application        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-10 22:52:32.627  INFO 19788 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2621 ms
2019-09-10 22:52:34.570  INFO 19788 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] com.de.webshop.Application        : Started Application in 5.707 seconds (JVM running for 12.314)
10-Sep-2019 22:52:34.683 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
10-Sep-2019 22:52:34.839 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
10-Sep-2019 22:52:34.893 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
10-Sep-2019 22:52:35.665 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [830] milliseconds.
10-Sep-2019 22:52:35.665 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [771] milliseconds.
10-Sep-2019 22:52:35.666 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/Webshop_war_exploded] startup failed due to previous errors
10-Sep-2019 22:52:35.687 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [1.004] ms
[2019-09-10 10:52:35,721] Artifact Webshop:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

```
10-Sep-2019 22:52:28.622 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
10-Sep-2019 22:52:32.627 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
10-Sep-2019 22:52:34.893 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Fehler beim Senden der 'Context Initialized' Benachrichtigung an den Listener aus der Klasse [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:262)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1728)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:689)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:689)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
10-Sep-2019 22:52:35.672 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
10-Sep-2019 22:52:35.700 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

### My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Webshop</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

### Application

```
package com.de.webshop;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }



}
```

I expected seeing my Application running on Tomcat, but i got this error.

Thanks for help!